# Trying to understand basic regex functions in C++

Tags: c++, regex, expression

I've done regular expressions in Perl for years and am now trying to utilize them in C++. Having some problems though. I want to parse through a string such as `translate(0.0,-572.36218)` and grab the 2 numerical values.

Here's what I have so far:

```
std::cmatch m;
std::regex e("([-|\.|0-9]*),([-|\.|0-9]*)" );  

std::regex_search ("translate(0.0,-572.36218)",m,e);
float xTransform = atof(m[1].first);
float yTransform = atof(m[2].first);
```

However when I look at the values in the debugger here's what I see:

```
m[0].first = "0.0,-572.36218)"
m[1].first = "0.0,-572.36218)"
m[3].first = "-572.36218)";
```

If I use a regex debugging tool (like The Regex Coach) I can see that my regular expression is syntactically correct. I guess I just don't know if I'm doing this right, or how to extract the data I need from the `cmatch` instance.

UPDATE:
I must really be missing something, because if I change my regular expression to just this:

```
std::regex e("([0-9])");
```

m returns as being only 2 entries deep and each entry's first element = "0.0,-572.36218)".  Why this is matching the parenthesis is beyond me. And the [0-9] seem to have no effect.. it just matches every character. Very fristrating. :(

Comment: Now the question that should have been asked first - which C++11 compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using MVS Express 2012.

Answer (score 2):

You should have used `\\.`. When you used `\.`, it matched whole string - because `\.` was escaped by C into simply `.`. Later that `.` was multiplied by `*` in `[-|.|0-9]*` to match anything.

Comment: No. Inside a character class `.` is just a literal dot. In a character class there are only 4 chars that have a special meaning: `-\]` and `^` but only at the first position inside the class. [Character classes](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/#character_classes)

Comment: True for most regex engines in general. But this is not true for c++11 in this particular case, believe it or not - maybe it has something to do with `|` usage inside `[]`.

Comment: Have you tested it? I am not into c++ biz, so don't have the possibility to test it, but I can't  believe this. A `|` is inside a character class also only a literal character.

Comment: The only compiler I have access to which claims to support C++11 is g++ 4.7.2 (Ubuntu 12.10). And, I have to say that its regex implementation is **total garbage** - it crashes or misbehaves even for most basic tasks. It does not seem to even support `[]` without providing extra regex options like `std::regex_constants::egrep`. So, I would say that with g++ implementation anything unexpected is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out the need to escape the back-slashes in your RE. C++11 offers an alternative to that: raw string literals. For example:

```
std::regex e(R"(([-|\.|0-9]*),([-|\.|0-9]*))");
```

Note that the opening delimiter here is `"(` and the closing delimiter is `)"`, so I've added an extra "(" and ")" to your string.

The heavy use of `\` makes raw string literals particularly handy when defining REs.

Comment: Jerry, this raw string literal would NOT work as is because of the need to use `)` inside the string. You would have to use `R"delim((...)...(...))delim"` for this to work [(link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#New_string_literals). For just couple extra backslashes, using raw literal seems like too much trouble.